# Printing russian text in mpdf showing?

Tags: mpdf

I am getting questions marks when I am trying to print our the text, and I am using UTF-8 encoding. So why it's showing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that those answering this question have something work with. Also let us know what you've tried, what went wrong and anything else you can think of that would help us help you.

Comment: I fixed by changing the font. I have used custom font and thats dose not support russian. so i changed it to Arial.

Comment: Cool. Consider removing this question then, or answering it yourself and accepting the answer, so tha the question does not show as unanswered anymore.

Comment: I can delete it but I think this could help someone else. And I can not answer it to myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use a font supporting russian characters, not all fonts contain other than latin alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **mode** on object creation

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => 'UTF-8']);
```

if you are sure that your html is utf-8